# How to extract nested data objects from an online JSON API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

Here is the link for the api - *https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/unofficial/covid19india.org/statewise*

I tried using this Jquery code. I want to retrieve the data of each individual state, for my project but I am unable to access them from the code given below.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/unofficial/covid19india.org/statewise', function(data) 
{
    var total_cases = data.total.cases
    var deaths = data.total.deaths
    var recovered = data.total.recovered
    var new_cases = data.total.active
    $(".total_cases").html(total_cases);
    $(".deaths").html(deaths);
    $(".recovered").html(recovered);
    $(".new_cases").html(new_cases);
});
```

My question is about

Comment: You should be using `data.data` since the server responds with a object containing the `data` property.

Comment: Please atleast use a console.log or debugger keyword to what actually is `data` first.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `data.data`

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/unofficial/covid19india.org/statewise', function(data) 
{

    var total_cases = data.data.total.active;
    var deaths =  data.data.total.deaths;
    var recovered =  data.data.total.recovered;
    var new_cases = data.data.total.active;
    $(".total_cases").html(total_cases);
    $(".deaths").html(deaths);
    $(".recovered").html(recovered);
    $(".new_cases").html(new_cases);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
total cases <span class="total_cases"></span>
deaths <span class="deaths"></span>
recovered <span class="recovered"></span>
new cases <span class="new_cases"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference to the data in the answer of the Api was incorrect, you have to check the documentation

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/unofficial/covid19india.org/statewise', function(responseApi) 
{
      try{
      var total_cases = responseApi.data.total.cases || 0
      var deaths = responseApi.data.total.deaths || 0
      var recovered = responseApi.data.total.recovered || 0
      var new_cases = responseApi.data.total.active || 0 
      $(".total_cases").html(total_cases);
      $(".deaths").html(deaths);
      $(".recovered").html(recovered);
      $(".new_cases").html(new_cases);
    }
    catch(error){
      console.error("Error processing data => " + error.message )
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a>Total Cases: <a><a class= "total_cases"><a/><div>
<div><a>Deaths : <a><a class= "deaths"><a/><div>
<div><a>Recovered : <a><a class= "recovered"><a/><div>
<div><a>New Cases : <a><a class= "new_cases"><a/><div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers already stated, that you were accessing the wrong properties. 
If you have Firefox installed you could easy check the data structure of the response

[image]

The next thing is, that your example is just getting the total numbers, but you wanted to get or show the data of each individual state, so you have to iterate through the statewise property.

Here is an example:

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/unofficial/covid19india.org/statewise', function(result) 
{
    addRow($("#resultTable tfoot"), result.data.total);
    result.data.statewise.forEach(el=>addRow($("#resultTable tbody"),el));
    
});

function addRow(parent, el)
{
  var tr = $("<tr/>");
  
  tr.append($("<td>"+(el.state == undefined?"Overall":el.state)+"</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>"+el.confirmed+"</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>"+el.recovered+"</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>"+el.deaths+"</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>"+el.active+"</td>"));
  parent.append(tr);
}
```

```css
th{ text-align:left; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resultTable"  style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Confirmed</th>
      <th>Recovered</th>
      <th>Deaths</th>
      <th>Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  
  </tfoot>
 </table>
```